# c# uploading data error -> return "�" for space

Tags: c#-4.0, compiler-errors, syntax-error, symbols

i am using c# with http helper and using stream reader to read a text. But When i upload a text file containing this text

"Look  exactly what I found on @ eBay! Willy Lee LifeLike  Chatting Butler Prop Motion Sen"

the space is replced by "�" and used in the code.

Code for reading the text is:-

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filepath);
        string text = "";
        while ((text = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                list.Add(text); 
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        return list;
```

list contains this data-
"Look��exactly�what�I�found�on�@�eBay!�Willy�Lee�LifeLike��Chatting�Butler�Prop�Motion�Sen"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like encoding problem - I have had such text problems, when a text is multibyte encoded and shown in a non-unicode based webpage like a Windows-1252 or CP-125X or such.

Here looks like the same - text looks [UTF-8 encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) and is displayed in ansi mode, so here the spaces are "special" spaces like these M$ Word puts sometimes, and the english characters are single byte as is the UTF-8 format (forr all chars below ASCII code 128) and this means they are compatible with ANSI codetable and visible correctly.

Or option 2 if it written in a file, and this text is saved like that, witout BOM in the beginning, the text editor may not understand that the context is unicode and opens it in ansi /regular ascii mode/.

If you give more details from where the data is read and where is saved and opened, I can give more concrete details.